# Removing Unwanted text before launching URL

Tags: wordpress, jquery-plugins

Whenever I am hitting any URL containing : cablevision.com
I get the below message due to network/firewall of my company:

> This page can’t be displayed
>
> - Make sure the web address https://bitbucket.cablevision.com is correct.
> - Look for the page with your search engine.
> - Refresh the page in a few minutes.

I have to remove 'cablevision.com' from URL manually and launch it again.

Can someone please let me know any plugin to do this every time I launch any URL containing 'cablevision.com'.

Comment: Why do you want to visit cablevision.com urls? 

It is not clear what you are trying to do, as unless you have access to a domain from this ISP, you are not going to be able to. (unless you want to fake it local in your DNS or host file for testing)